# Why are some bird species placed as family Incertae sedis while some families are simply monotypic?

Tags: ornithology, taxonomy

The Bananaquit and Western Spindalis are passerines of Incerta sedis. But species such as the Osprey, Limpkin and Olive Warbler belong to their own, monotypic, family.

Why aren't Bananaquit and Western Spindalis simply assigned to a new family?